# Angular 2 routing does not route

Tags: angular2-routing

The issue I am having is that I am not able to navigate to the new component that I created using the routes. It was working and still works fine with other components.
Here is the file where I create the outlet
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. Then I have multiple `routing` variable that will navigate to the needed parts of the website. With the new component, I am not able to access it. I created a new component and named it `RegisterPageComponent`. In my `app.routing.ts` I added a new field to `appRoutes`with the following format
`{
    path: 'register', 
    component: RegisterPageComponent
}`
When I try to access localhost:4200/register, I don't get anything. My RegisterPageComponent holds a default `works!` value

Comment: Pls provide your code

Answer (score 0):

Please read below link and try to implement same solutions.

https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-routing